# Where are the best locations to farm elites in Act 3?

Tags: diablo-iii

What are the best spots in Act 3?  I know a lot of people have just gotten to the highest mob level in the game and want to know where everyone else has been grinding mobs.

Answer (score 5):

Act 3 loot is the best in the game, so if you can farm these mobs consistently you totally should.  The best areas I've found are:

- [Underbridge](http://www.diablowiki.net/The_Underbridge) ([Rakkis Crossing](http://www.diablowiki.net/Rakkis_Crossing) waypoint then up and to the right) – This area spawns about 60-65% of the time.  Guaranteed one elite and a possible resplendent chest.  Find the elite, explore the small dungeon, and teleport out..
- [The Keep Depths](http://www.diablowiki.net/The_Keep_Depths) level 2 – The most elite dense of the three Keep Depths levels.  Usually 4-6 elites found.  Can be accessed by going to the Keep Depths level 1 waypoint and immediately going down a level.  You will run into [Soul Rippers](http://www.diablowiki.net/Soul_Ripper) here but they are a lot less potent post-1.03.
- The Keep Depths level 3 – Usually 2-4 elites.  Smaller than the Keep Depths level 2.  You can usually find an elite pack within 1-2 minutes near the waypoints.
- The [Fortified Bunker](http://www.diablowiki.net/Fortified_Bunker) – The Fortified Bunker or the [Barracks](http://www.diablowiki.net/The_Barracks) will spawn outside [the Arreat gate](http://www.diablowiki.net/The_Arreat_Gate).  It’s a bit smaller (and easier) than the Barracks but will have between 4-10 elites and a resplendent chest in level 2.
- [Arreat Crater](http://www.diablowiki.net/Arreat_Crater) level 1,2 – 3-5 elites each.
- The [Core of Arreat](http://diablo.gamepedia.com/The_Core_of_Arreat) - 2-3 elites.  [Hulking Phasebeasts](http://d3db.com/lore/i/hulking-phasebeast) do spawn and can be very difficult.  Skip them and face Azmodan if the Phasebeasts get particularly tough affixes.
- [Tower of the Damned](http://diablo.gamepedia.com/Tower_of_the_Damned_Level_1), [Heart of the Damned](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Heart_of_the_Damned) - 1-3 elites per level (4 levels).  Usually 2-3, although you can run into both Phasebeasts and Soul Rippers on some levels.
- [Siegebreaker](http://www.diablowiki.net/Siegebreaker_Assault_Beast) – An easy set boss if you can handle the reflect. Make sure you kill him after you have your five stacks.  One reason not to do Siegebreaker is selecting his quest doesn’t give you access to all the that killing [Azmodan](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Azmodan) or [Cydaea](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Cydaea) will.
- Cydaea + Azmodan – Kill both if you can.  Azmodan is extremely but post 1.03 Cydaea gives the Wizard/Demon Hunter serious. If she’s too much, just select the very last waypoint in the [Heart of Sin](http://www.ign.com/wikis/diablo-3/Heart_of_Sin) quest and kill Azmodan once you have your five stacks.

Source: http://www.diablo3strategyguide.com/inferno-act-3-runs

Comment: me and my friend does the keep 1-3 and then underbridge + seigebreaker, very good run and lots of nice drops